# Word to describe parent or category word

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word...

> Red is a color
>       Blue is a color
>       *Color* is a ____ of blue and red

What word goes in the blank?

Comment: Turquoise is a **shade** of blue?

Comment: @deadrat - "Hue" are right about that, but I think the O.P. is looking for ***hypernym***.

Comment: @J.R. Color my face red.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you might be looking for ***hypernym***.

From [Google's definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning%20of%20hypernym):

> **hypernym** (noun)
>   a word with a broad meaning that more specific words fall under; a superordinate.
>   For example, *color* is a hypernym of *red*.

Answer (score 1):

Color is a **generic term** for blue, red, ...

> Definition: Relating to or descriptive of an entire group or class
>
> Examples:
>
> - *Cancer is a generic term for a group of diseases in which
>   cells proliferate wildly*.
> - *Furniture is a generic term for chairs, tables etc*.